# How to install wxpython 2.8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, wxpython

I need to run a python script for the gui of a software I need to use. Unfortunately, this software has not been updated in a while, and need to install wxpython 2.8 for it to work. I have looked a previous posts, but I get this when I run it.

> Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

I am using Python 2.7 (Need it for the software), and Linux Mint(Ubuntu/Debian).

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Checked pypi, seems the oldest version is 2.8.11.0, so you can try your luck with `pip`:

```
$ pip install wxPython==2.8.11.0
```

Otherwise, please check out the binary packages on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/

Or, in the worst case, you may need to compile it yourself (e.g., to support Win64 platform)

Comment: I am getting this: $ pip install wxPython==2.8.11.0
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wxPython==2.8.11.0 (from versions: 4.0.0a1, 4.0.0a2, 4.0.0a3, 4.0.0b1, 4.0.0b2, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.7.post1, 4.0.7.post2, 4.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wxPython==2.8.11.0

Comment: that means your specific platform is not supported. Try to download from the link I mentioned above.

Comment: [wxPython 2.8.11.0](https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/2.8.11.0/) (and BTW 2.9) don't have downloadable files at PyPI. Downloads at PyPI are available starting with version 4.0.